# Why Won't This Cast Return the Correct Methods? (Ephesoft)

Tags: java, casting, io, document, jdom

Okay, so I have been looking at the sample code below from the Ephesoft Developer's Guide...

```
//import java.io.File;
//
//import javax.xml.transform.Result;
//import javax.xml.transform.Source;
//import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
//import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
//import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
//import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
//import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
//import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
//import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
//
//import org.w3c.dom.Document;
//import org.w3c.dom.Element;
//import org.w3c.dom.Node;
//import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.ephesoft.dcma.script.IScripts;
//--------------------------------------

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;

//import com.ephesoft.dcma.script.IJDomScript;


/**
 * The <code>ScriptDocumentAssembler</code> class represents the script execute structure. Writer of scripts plug-in should implement this IScript
 * interface to execute it from the scripting plug-in. Via implementing this interface writer can change its java file at run time.
 * Before the actual call of the java Scripting plug-in will compile the java and run the new class file.
 * 
 * @author Ephesoft
 * @version 1.0
 */

public class ScriptDocumentAssembler 
{

    private static final String BATCH_LOCAL_PATH = "BatchLocalPath";

    private static final String BATCH_INSTANCE_ID = "BatchInstanceIdentifier";

    private static final String EXT_BATCH_XML_FILE = "_batch.xml";

    private static final String DOCUMENTS = "Documents";

    private static final String DOCUMENT = "Document";

    private static final String PAGES = "Pages";

    private static final String PAGE = "Page";

    private static String ZIP_FILE_EXT = ".zip";

    /**
     * The <code>execute</code> method will execute the script written by the writer at run time with new compilation of java file. It
     * will execute the java file dynamically after new compilation.
     * 
     * @param document {@link Document}
     */
    public void execute(Document document, String fieldName, String docIdentifier) {
        System.out.println("*************  Inside ScriptDocumentAssembler scripts.");
        System.out.println("*************  Start execution of the ScriptDocumentAssembler scripts.");
        System.out.println("Custom ScriptDocumentAssembler, removing Document seperator sheets...");
        removeFirstPageOfDoc(document);
        boolean isWrite = true;
        //boolean isWrite = false;
        // write the document object to the XML file.
        if (isWrite) {
            writeToXML(document);
            System.out.println("*************  Successfully write the xml file for the ScriptDocumentAssembler scripts.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("************** No changes performed by ScriptDocumentAssembler scripts.");
        }
        System.out.println("*************  End execution of the ScriptDocumentAssembler scripts.");
    }

    private void removeFirstPageOfDoc(Document documentFile) {
        Element documentsList = (Element) documentFile.getChildren(DOCUMENTS).get(0);
        List<?> documentList = documentsList.getChildren(DOCUMENT);
        for (int documentIndex = 0; documentIndex < documentList.size(); documentIndex++) {
            Element document = (Element) documentList.get(documentIndex);
            System.out.println("Processing Document - " + document.getChildren("Identifier").get(0).getText());
            Element pages = (Element) document.getChildren(PAGES).get(0);
            List<?> pageList = pages.getChildren(PAGE);         
            Element page = (Element)pageList.get(0);            

            System.out.println(document.getChildren("Identifier").get(0).getText() + " Page Count = " + pageList.size());
            System.out.println("Removing page node " + page.getChildren("Identifier").get(0).getText() + " from " +
                    document.getChildren("Identifier").get(0).getText());
            pages.remove(page);             
            System.out.println(document.getChildren("Identifier").get(0).getText() + " Page Count = " + pageList.size());           
        }
    }

    private void writeToXML(Document document) {
        String batchLocalPath = null;
        List<?> batchLocalPathList = document.getRootElement().getChildren(BATCH_LOCAL_PATH);
        if (null != batchLocalPathList) {
            batchLocalPath = ((Element) batchLocalPathList.get(0)).getText();
        }
        if (null == batchLocalPath) {
                System.err.println("Unable to find the local folder path in batch xml file.");
            return;
        }
        String batchInstanceID = null;
        List<?> batchInstanceIDList = document.getRootElement().getChildren(BATCH_INSTANCE_ID);
        if (null != batchInstanceIDList) {
            batchInstanceID = ((Element) batchInstanceIDList.get(0)).getText();
        }
        if (null == batchInstanceID) {
            System.err.println("Unable to find the batch instance ID in batch xml file.");
            return;
        }
        String batchXMLPath = batchLocalPath.trim() + File.separator + batchInstanceID + File.separator + batchInstanceID
        + EXT_BATCH_XML_FILE;
        String batchXMLZipPath = batchXMLPath + ZIP_FILE_EXT;
        System.out.println("batchXMLZipPath************" + batchXMLZipPath);
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        File zipFile = new File(batchXMLZipPath);
        FileWriter writer = null;
        XMLOutputter out = new XMLOutputter();
        try {
            if (zipFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Found the batch xml zip file.");
                outputStream = getOutputStreamFromZip(batchXMLPath, batchInstanceID + EXT_BATCH_XML_FILE);
                out.output(document, outputStream);
            } else {
                writer = new java.io.FileWriter(batchXMLPath);
                out.output(document, writer);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static OutputStream getOutputStreamFromZip(final String zipName, final String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ZipOutputStream stream = null;
        stream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(zipName + ZIP_FILE_EXT)));
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
        stream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        return stream;
    }

}
```

Note I have not changed anything from the original code, but I added the jdom and ephesoft jars to my build path. However, within the removeFirstPageOfDoc method, I am still getting a bunch of errors related to the casting.For example, the line `Element documentsList = (Element) documentFile.getChildren(DOCUMENTS).get(0);` should allow documentFile to gain access to the methods of Element, right? However, it still seems to only have access to the methods of type document. I was just wondering what the issue might be here and how I might go about resolving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, the line `Element documentsList = (Element) documentFile.getChildren(DOCUMENTS).get(0);` should allow documentFile to gain access to the methods of Element, right?

No, because casting has lower precedence than the dot operator. To cast `documentFile` to type `Element`, you would write this:

```
Element documentsList = ((Element) documentFile).getChildren(DOCUMENTS).get(0);
```

with parentheses around `(Element) documentFile`.

**Edited to add** *(incorporating information from the comments below)*:

However, according to [the Javadoc for `org.jdom.Document`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Document.html) and [that for `org.jdom.Element`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Element.html), they're both actual classes — neither one is an interface — and neither is a subtype of the other. This means that you can't actually cast from one to the other. (In Java, a cast doesn't let you convert an instance of one type into another type; in order for `((Type) reference)` to work, `reference` has to refer to an object that really does belong to type `Type`. Since an object can never be an instance of both `Element` and `Document`, the compiler won't even allow this sort of cast here.)

Instead, the person who wrote this sample-code probably should have written this:

```
Element documentsList =
    documentFile.getRootElement().getChildren(DOCUMENTS).get(0);
```

which uses the `getRootElement()` method (which returns the document's root element) rather than casting to `Element` (which would try to convince the compiler that the document simply *is* an element).

Comment: Just tried that, did `Element documentsList = ((Element) documentFile).getChildren(DOCUMENTS).get(0);` However, now the compiler is throwing an error stating: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Element`

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer: O.K., now that I've actually looked at the Javadoc for `org.jdom.Document` and `org.jdom.Element`, I think that you simply can't do what you're trying to do. `Document` is a completely separate class from `Element`; an instance of `Document` can never be an instance of `Element`, so if `document` is an instance of `Document`, then `((Element) document)` can never work.

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer: Probably what you want is `documentFile.getRootElement()` (which returns the document's root element) rather than `((Element) documentFile)` (which tries to convince the compiler that the document simply *is* an element).

Comment: @ruakh So what your basically saying is this sample code I got was probably never tested prior to being uploaded to the developer's guide/wiki? And I'll give that alternative a try right now.

Comment: KK, so it at least doesn't throw any errors when I do: `Element documentsList = documentFile.getRootElement().getChildren(DOCUMENTS).get(0);`. I guess I'll try modifying the code as necessary and hope I don't run into any runtime issues. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer: You're welcome! And yeah, you can't always trust sample code. It hardly ever comes with unit-tests and continuous integration. :-P

Answer (score 1):

ruakh is right, but you need to do the next level as well.

```
Element documentsList = (Element)(((Document) documentFile).getChildren(DOCUMENTS).get(0));
```

Of course, in JDOM 2.x (with correct generic typing) this is all all easier....

```
Element documentsList = doumentFile.getChildren(DOCUMENTS).get(0);
```

rolfl

Comment: I tried switching to jdom2, but I still can't do `Element documentsList = doumentFile.getChildren(DOCUMENTS).get(0);` . Still had to do the casting with `Element document = (Element) documentList.get(documentIndex);` to get it to work.